# JDBC Update on Oracle failed to commit

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sql-update

I have JDBC Dao Object, and used PreparedStatements to do UPDATE a row at a table in my DB.

I have other methods such as SELECT and INSERT which are successful (insert-commit works).
But the update, just does not commit the changes (does not work at all). While the same UPDATE statement works from Oracle SQLServer directly.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class StaffDAO {
    private Connection conn;

    public StaffDAO() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Oracle Driver not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@db01.xxxdev.com:1521:training",
                    "training", "training");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver manager failed");
        }
    }

    public ResultSet getAllResultSet() {
        String sql = "select * from ben_staff";
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;

    }

    public Staff viewEmployee(String id) throws Exception {
        Staff st = new Staff();
        String sql = "SELECT * from BEN_STAFF where BEN_STAFF.id =\'" + id
                + "\'";
        // String psql = "SELECT * FROM BEN_STAFF WHERE ID = ?";

        Statement statement = null;
        // PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
        try {
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            // pstatement = conn.prepareStatement(psql);
            // pstatement.setString(1, id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Create Statement failed");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            // rs = pstatement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                st.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
                st.setLastName(rs.getString("LASTNAME"));
                st.setFirstName(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                st.setMi(rs.getString("MI"));
                st.setAddress(rs.getString("ADDRESS"));
                st.setCity(rs.getString("CITY"));
                st.setState(rs.getString("STATE"));
                st.setTelephone(rs.getString("TELEPHONE"));
                st.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                statement.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st;
    }

    public boolean insert(String id, String last, String first, String mi,
            String address, String city, String state, String telephone,
            String email) {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        String psql = "insert into ben_staff (id, lastname, firstname, mi, address, city, state, telephone, email)"
                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(psql);
            // pstmt.setString(1,st.getId());
            // pstmt.setString(2, st.getLastName());
            // pstmt.setString(3, st.getFirstName());
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, last);
            pstmt.setString(3, first);
            pstmt.setString(4, mi);
            pstmt.setString(5, address);
            pstmt.setString(6, city);
            pstmt.setString(7, state);
            pstmt.setString(8, telephone);
            pstmt.setString(9, email);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean update(String id, String last, String first, String mi,
            String address, String city, String state, String telephone,
            String email) {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        String psql = "update ben_staff set lastname=?, firstname=?, mi=?, address=?, city=?, state=?,"
                + " telephone=?, email=? where id=?";

        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(psql);
            pstmt.setString(1, last);
            pstmt.setString(2, first);
            pstmt.setString(3, mi);
            pstmt.setString(4, address);
            pstmt.setString(5, city);
            pstmt.setString(6, state);
            pstmt.setString(7, telephone);
            pstmt.setString(8, email);
            pstmt.setString(9, id);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try{
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException exx){
                System.out.println("Update Rollback Failed");
            }
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you are in `autoCommit`, so calling `commit()` or `rollback()` should always result in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

What does `pstmt.executeUpdate();` return?  That would tell you how many rows are being updated.  Something like

```
int numRows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println( "Update modified " + numRows + " rows." );
```

My guess is that your update isn't actually modifying any rows.  That would imply that the `id` being passed in was incorrect.  Remember that string comparisons in SQL Server are case insensitive by default while they are case sensitive by default in Oracle.

Comment: Yes. That expression returns 0, although I checked I had the correct variables passed, set and everything.

Comment: @mediocr3 - OK.  So the `update` is being committed.  It's just not updating any rows.  What is the `id` value that is being passed in?  Are you sure that a row with that value (case sensitive) exists in the table?

Comment: I had the correct test id passed. Although, it (the Update statement) works directly just from SQLDeveloper. Code runs as, it does not throw any exception as to any errors during the update. It just returns 0 during executeUpdate..  I wonder as to how ??

Comment: @mediocr3 - An `update`xthat succeeds and does not update any rows more or less guarantees that your predicate is wrong.  The row does not exist or is not visible to the current session.

Comment: I found that I used chars on id which is fixed-sized.. that I had to pad the characters to full length w. spaces. Although SELECT seems to work without padding. So I found out why..

Comment: @mediocr3 - Never use `char` as a data type when defining columns in a table.  Use `varchar2`.  Particularly when the data isn't actually fixed width.